# Should I write follow up email to HR

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, human-resources, email, follow-up

I interview 2 rounds in one company. Both rounds were awesome. After the interview I didn't hear from HR then I called her after 3 to 4 day. HR said she will inform me within 2 days but again, I didn't hear from her. Now it has been more than 10 days.

I thinking to write an email instead of calling. Should I write an email or not?

This is my email

> Subject -  Follow up - abc Position
>
> Hi abc, Thank you for your time. This is follow up email on abc
> position I interviewed at abc. I’m looking forward to hearing any
> updates you can share, and don’t hesitate to contact me if you have
> any questions or concerns.

Comment: If you email, have the spelling and grammar checked before you send it.

Comment: @SolarMike - Thank you. I edited my question. Pl check my email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should follow up. You should send email reminders to check the status.

One suggestion, in the email, include the dates when you were interviewed, if someones wants to look up the records, it makes a bit easier for them.

Also, try calling them again, 10 days is not a short time. They should have reached out to you already.